# Run a list of songs in python pygame randomly(from the list) and indefinitely(without having to use a button to manually change the song)

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I have a background music running on my game. I have a list of multiple songs and I want them to just constantly be played in a random order(that is why I imported `choice` on there) but it only runs once on the user-defined function that I have called play. When I put `loops =-1` it only runs the random song that is chosen over and over again. I want it to change songs without having to manually change it(not needing to use a button or something to change songs).How do I do that?

Here is the code(This are the codes that I am using in the game right now to play the music):

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from random import choice


pygame.mixer.init()

Music_list=["song1.mp3","song2.mp3","song3.mp3"]

#Play the backgound music
def play():
       Song=choice(Music_list)
       pygame.mixer.music.load(Song)
       pygame.mixer.music.play() # if i put a loops=-1 here, it will only run that one song forever. It wont change. And if I have nothing there, it only plays once 
play()
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

since you are iterating infefinitely after the song was chose you are always getting the same song.

you want to move your loop to be invoking the whole play function

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from random import choice


pygame.mixer.init()

MUSIC_LIST=["song1.mp3","song2.mp3","song3.mp3"]

#Play the backgound music
def play():
       Song=choice(MUSIC_LIST)
       pygame.mixer.music.load(Song)
       pygame.mixer.music.play()


while True:
    play()
```

Comment: Why are you importing `tkinter` but not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mixer.music.get_busy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy) to test test if any sound is being mixed. Play the next song when a song finishes:

```py
import pygame
from random import choice

pygame.mixer.init()

Music_list=["song1.mp3","song2.mp3","song3.mp3"]
current_list = []

def play():
       song = choice(Music_list)
       pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
       pygame.mixer.music.play()

while True:

    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        play()

    # [...]
```

Improve the play method to make sure no track is played twice:

```py
Music_list=["song1.mp3","song2.mp3","song3.mp3"]
current_list = []

def play():
       global current_list
       if not current_list:
           current_list = Music_list[:]
           random.shuffle(current_list)

       song = current_list[0]
       current_list.pop(0)
       pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
       pygame.mixer.music.play()
```